# Column selection in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Customer table with 200 columns I want to create another table from Customer table which should have only 190 columns.
How can i skip few columns in hive from base table?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Why don't you use a `CTAS` and select the columns that you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE NewCustomer AS    
SELECT col1, col2, ... col190
FROM Customer;
```

From [Hive Data Definition Language](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect%28CTAS%29)

Comment: i dun want to type 1..190 columns